# How to compress multiple image in angular? here i attached code which can compress only 1 image at a time

Tags: angular, image-compression

How to compress multiple image in angular? here i attached code which can compress only 1 image at a time help me to solve this.
i dont know how to make  loop for multiple images, i did not get any documentation  for 'ngx-image-compress'

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgxImageCompressService} from 'ngx-image-compress';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="compressFile()">Upload and compress Image</button>
      <img *ngIf="imgResultBeforeCompress" [src]="imgResultBeforeCompress" alt="">
      <img *ngIf="imgResultAfterCompress" [src]="imgResultAfterCompress" alt="">
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private imageCompress: NgxImageCompressService) {}
  
  imgResultBeforeCompress:string;
  imgResultAfterCompress:string;

  compressFile() {
  
    this.imageCompress.uploadFile().then(({image, orientation}) => {
    
      this.imgResultBeforeCompress = image;
      console.warn('Size in bytes was:', this.imageCompress.byteCount(image));
      
      this.imageCompress.compressFile(image, orientation, 50, 50).then(
        result => {
          this.imgResultAfterCompress = result;
          console.warn('Size in bytes is now:', this.imageCompress.byteCount(result));
        }
      );
      
    });
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got you right, hope one of the below helps:

- As per the documentation (https://github.com/dfa1234/ngx-image-compress#readme), it seems like you can only select one file at a time. So if you want the user to upload multiple files, go and compress the image every time the user press the button to upload and save the result in a list of images.
  You can loop over the list of images after that and perform whatever operations you want.
- If you want to use this library for compression only. You can use a normal input of type file, and then when the use selects the images, run `this.imageCompress.compressFile` on every image to get the compressed image.

Comment: i found the better one, here it is https://github.com/nivikamal/ng2-image-compress 
it works a per my requirement, now i can compress multiple images at a time

Comment: As I wrote in another answer, you can use now `this.imageCompress.uploadMultipleFiles()`

Answer (score 0):

There have been an update and now you can upload multiple files at once in `ngx-image-compress` using `uploadMultipleFiles()` method.

You can run the demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-compress-sample

```js
uploadMultipleFiles() {
   this.imageCompress.uploadMultipleFiles().then((multipleFiles: UploadResponse[]) => {
     console.warn(`${multipleFiles.length} files selected`);
   });
}
```